# How to make android recognize app as Bluetooth peripheral device (BLE Device)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing one android application and I want to make an android app that works as a Bluetooth peripheral device (BLE Device).
I am new to android Bluetooth.

I have tried advertising, but unable to scan it as a BLE Device. I tried searching on the net but didn't find anything.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at this example here: https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver

Comment: @M.Kotzjan thank you for your comment will try that